# What type to upload image within theme options?

Tags: images, themes, uploads, options

I want to get option to change logo within my option theme. I use this code:

```
    array("name" => "Upload Logo",
    "desc" => "Choose an image",
    "id" => $shortname."_logo_img",
    "type" => "upload",
    "std" => "",
),
```

when I execute on my theme option page, nothing appear. I change that type to "file" and "image", that's same as before, nothing appear. I don't want to take URL, like when I set the type as "text".

Answer (score 0):

If using image radio buttons, define a directory path here is code. I hope its going work.

```
$imagepath =  get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/';

    $options = array();

    $options[] = array( "name" => __('Logo', 'prothemeus'),
                        "desc" => __('Upload your logo', 'prothemeus'),
                        "id" => "pt_logo",
                        "type" => "upload");
```

Comment: just change the name according to your need, i just forget to change them.

Comment: I use the switch-case in my form class. I change from text type to file and I add an input button to submit image. The button is appearing but doesn't uppload the file. Here I change my type code:

type="<?php echo $value['file']; ?>"

any idea?

Answer (score -2):

Check this code out ... works for 1 instance, multiple instances is not working.

http://www.webmaster-source.com/2013/02/06/using-the-wordpress-3-5-media-uploader-in-your-plugin-or-theme/#comment-37213

Comment: Answers in the form of "Look here for a solution" are less than ideal. Answers should be self-explanatory, even if linked resources should become unreachable.
Linking to *additional external resources* for *further information* is a good idea.